# IGCSE Maths: Fractions Problem

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, fractional-part

I am currently trying to study for my IGCSE maths paper... I am stuck on this question ... can anybody help??

If `3/5` of people in a theatre buy a snack during interval, and of those who buy a snack 5/7 buy ice cream, what fraction of the people in the theatre buy ice cream??

Comment: "and of those who buy ice cream"...?...the question seems incomplete

Comment: There are some words missing. Also, what are your thoughts? What is your question?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: What if there are $35$ people in the theater?

Comment: If there are 35 people in the theater, the theater will go under.

Comment: Umm... why do you have trouble with this?  There is an simple answer and if you know it you can't not know it.  And if you don't know it read a book.  They will *all* give the exactly same answer as how to do this.

Comment: This is not Reddit, so your question will be closed if you do not include your work. If you don't know where to start, you can tell us where the question has come from (which you have done), or indicate the topics you have learned that are related to the question. See more at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You might also want to format mathematics on this site, which you can learn at the [MathJax reference page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @fleablood We were all beginners once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note for the future: generally, people on Math.SE don't like it when you ask 'homework questions' if you don't show your attempts. It also helps to provide *some* context, though the degree to which this is necessary varies from question to question. In this case, you mentioned that it was from an IGCSE maths paper, which to me is enough context for people to gauge what level of mathematics you are working at, meaning that people can tailor their responses.

Now that is out of the way, here is a hint to your question:

What we are looking to do is translate this wordy problem into an equation that we can manipulate. Pay attention to the details: '$3/5$ of people in a theatre buy a snack during an interval'. In other words, for every $5$ people, $3$ of them buy a snack. Now, what is $5/7$ of $\frac{3}{5}$? Pay attention to which operator ($+,-,\div,\times)$ you are using when you calculate the answer.